# IN operator in AWS Keyspaces CQL query not working

Tags: cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/working-with-queries.html#in.select), the `IN` operator is supported in CQL queries. However, the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name IN ('system')
```

fails with:

```
Invalid WHERE Clause on table. Valid WHERE Clauses are equality clauses with keyspace_name or keyspace_name and table_name.
```

If I just use comparison by equality, it works fine:

```
SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables WHERE keyspace_name = 'system'
```

Am I doing something wrong, are there maybe some limitations when it comes to the `IN` operator that I have overseen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the IN operator is not supported on system tables at the time of this post. Is this query part of a third party tool or driver where you do not have the ability to change the code? If so which tool/driver?

Comment: It is part of a third party driver (datastax) which is already used in the system and which I am trying to reuse to connect to AWS Keyspaces too (i.e. the system should be configurable to either use AWS Keyspaces or a standalone Cassandra deployment, hence I am trying to reuse the existing Cassandra configurations and infrastructure).

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Which driver and which version?

Comment: It is `com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.17.0`. In the meantime I found out that on our side we specify `DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REFRESHED_KEYSPACES` driver option which causes the driver to run the query with the `IN` operator on the `system_schema.tables` table. When I removed it (together with some other changes unrelated to this issue), it started working properly and now I am able to connect to AWS Keyspaces.

Comment: Good find. Yes. leaving ```advanced.metadata.schema.refreshed-keyspaces``` in the configuration or ```DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REFRESHED_KEYSPACES``` will just refresh schema for all keyspaces.